# How can I replace garage door opener remotes?

Tags: garage-door-opener

I have a working garage door opener, and at least the button on the receiver works too (the thing inside the garage with the button on it) but I have no remote clickers to it and it's pretty old anyway.

There's a thin double wire that goes into the receiver. Seems standard. It's an old Sears garage door opener.

I did some research on here and found a post linking to youdoitstore.com garage door parts site:

I found some digicode and multi-code receiver sets.  Anyone know the difference or know whether a replacement here would even work? Here's what I was considering..

- [MULTI-CODE 2 CAR RADIO SET 2022](http://www.youdoitstore.com/product_p/202200.htm)
- [DIGI-CODE 2 CAR RADIO SET](http://www.youdoitstore.com/product_p/dc2002.htm)

What is the difference between multi and digi code?

One last thing, I also have a key entry to the opener, which is a separate thin wire from the key to the main opener unit. I think this will continue to work since it's a separate wire altogether.  I'll consider other brands and models, I just like the idea of having a couple clickers or even a key chain remote too.

Comment: found a few more, liftmaster this time - http://www.aaaremotes.com/liungadooppl2.html  - http://www.aaaremotes.com/liungadooppl1.html

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the exact same problem with my garage door using a general purpose relay output wireless transmitter / receiver module I purchased from eBay. The receiver module for inside the garage operates from a +12VDC power supply which I purchased for low cost from Goodwill. The normally open relay contact of the receiver is wired in across the same wire pair used by the inside door open push button. The existing push button is designed to short across the two wires that run to the garage door opener. The added relay connections need to be wired in parallel to the switch so that they short across the same wires when the remote is activated.

[image]

The trigger buttons are small key fob type push button controls that operate from a standard type of coin battery.

[image]

Note that models on eBay change often and it is a good idea to search for a unit that comes with multiple fobs and to purchase a spare unit if you ever think you will need replacements. Some sellers will add additional fobs to your order for an additional small charge. The search to use on eBay is **Wireless Remote Control**.

The whole setup cost me about a third of the lower priced options that you have linked to. The unit I purchased was a two channel device with an A and B button on the fob and so one setup was deployed to run both of my garage door openers.

These come with the remote transmit code set to some default value and it is advisable to change that code to some random code that you select. Changing the code entails some work with a small electronics soldering iron inside both the receiver and the transmitter.

Comment: +1 But some readers may need more explanation of what *wired in across the same wire pair* means. A reference to momentary contact and parallel vs. series perhaps.

Comment: @bib - I'll edit in a more detailed comment.

Answer (score 1):

To the the garage door opener's manufacture's website and buy a replacement remote. Your manual, or the remote's manual should describe how to reprogram it.

Also, usually you can buy a replacement remote from ebay cheaper than your manufacturer, just make sure the part numbers match.